# Overloading of operator new in C++

Tags: c++

I want to overload 'new' operator. I made one Header file where macro for 'new' is declared.

**HeaderNew.h**

```
#ifndef MYNEW_H
#define MYNEW_H

#define  new    new(__FILE__, __LINE__)

void* operator new(std::size_t size, const char* file, unsigned int line);

#endif
```

**myNew.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>   
#include<malloc.h>
#include<cstddef>
#include "mynew.h"
using namespace std;

#undef      new

void* operator new(std::size_t size, const char* file, unsigned int line){
    void *ptr = malloc(size);
    cout << "This is overloaded new." << endl;
    cout << "File : " << file << endl;
    cout << "Line : " << line << endl;
    cout << "Size : " << size << endl;
    return ptr;
}
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mynew.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int * ptr1 = new int;
   cout << "Address : " << ptr1 << endl;
   //delete ptr1;
   return 0;
}
```

Here, I want to know the file name and line number of 'new' operator used in test.cpp . But i got a error as mentioned below.

error : declaration of ‘operator new’ as non-function in
    #define  new  new(**FILE**, **LINE**)

Can anyone tell me the reason for this error & its appropriate solution. Thanks in advance..:)

Comment: you are mixing up `operator new` and what is colloquially known as the `new` operator, the latter is a keyword built in the language and cannot (shouldn't) be redefined. The `new` operator calls `operator new` to allocate first the memory, then invokes the constructor of the passed object.

Comment: Even if that macro was legal wouldn't your function then expand to: `void* operator new(__FILE__, __LINE__)(std::size_t size, const char* file, unsigned int line);` ?

Comment: @vsoftco have you never heard of overloading `new`?

Comment: @immibis I heard about overloading `operator new`, not the keyword `new`. It seems the OP is re-defining a keyword: `#define  new    new(__FILE__, __LINE__)` which seems a sure recipe for disaster

Comment: @vsoftco Yes, he/she is using the preprocessor to replace `new` calls with his/her overloaded version that takes the file and line number. It's not portable, but in practice it will probably work, and it's not what the error is about. Apart from being a keyword and not a function, this is the same principle used by `assert`.

Comment: @immibis I see, he's actually calling the placement `new`, which calls his placement operator `new`. But it will change also the definition of `operator new`, so it's a mess...

Comment: this is redefinition, not overloading

Comment: @immibis I meant that OP intended to use the code so that calling `new Foo` will actually map to `new (...) Foo`, which is placement `new`, isn't it?

Comment: @immibis 5.3.4/13 "The first of these arguments has type `std::size_t` and the remaining arguments have the corresponding types of the expressions in the new-placement; such an expression is called a placement new-expression." Any overload of `new` that takes more than `size_t` is a placement `new`, second arg. doesn't necessarily need to be a pointer, although most of the time is.

Answer (score 3):

`#define`s work everywhere after the definition.

Which means this:

```
#define  new    new(__FILE__, __LINE__)
void* operator new(std::size_t size, const char* file, unsigned int line);
```

gets changed to this, by the preprocessor:

```
void* operator new(__FILE__, __LINE__)(std::size_t size, const char* file, unsigned int line);
```

See the problem?

Try moving the `#define` line after the declaration of `operator new`.

Also, be aware that this trick is not entirely robust - for example, it will break any other `operator new` declarations you have, or placement `new` calls (including in any standard headers that use placement `new`); "placement `new`" is a built-in overload of `operator new`.

Comment: @immibis...thnks 4 the comment. But still its not working after moving the #define line after the decleration of operator new...:(..you can also check in ur system. Its giving the same error.

Comment: @immibis...thanks 4 the comment.But still its not working after moving the #define line after the declaration of operator new...:(..You can also check in your system...Its giving the same error.